# JIRA Sub Task must get Epic's assignee

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I have an User Story which has an Epic linked to it. Now when I create a Sub-Task in the User Story, the Sub-Task must get the Epic's assignee.

Is this possible? Please explain.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I fear you cannot do this without additional plugins like [ScriptRunner](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner/server/overview). JQL [does not even support to query a parent of an issue](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRASERVER-31922). SR allows you to implement listeners to events like "issue created" and to run a Groovy script then. A issue created listener could look somehow like this:

```
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.CustomFieldManager;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.fields.CustomField;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.MutableIssue;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.IssueManager;
import com.atlassian.jira.bc.issue.IssueService

CustomFieldManager customFieldManager =
   ComponentAccessor.getCustomFieldManager();
IssueManager issueManager = ComponentAccessor.getIssueManager();
IssueService issueService = ComponentAccessor.getComponent(IssueService);
CustomField epicLinkField = 
   customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObjectByName('Epic Link');


//lookup the corresponding epic via the subtask's parent
MutableIssue epic = issueManager.getIssueObject(
    (String)issue.getParentObject().getCustomFieldValue(epicLinkField)
);

//assign subtask to the assignee of the epic
def validateAssignResult = issueService.validateAssign(epic.getAssignee(), 
   issue.id, epic.getAssigneeId());
issueService.assign(epic.getAssignee(), validateAssignResult)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options. Script Runner is one of them as mdo already answered.

If you don't want to write a groovy script, you can also take a look at the [Jira Misc Workflow Extensions](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.innovalog.jmwe.jira-misc-workflow-extensions/server/overview) plugin. It contains a postfunction called 'Copy field from linked issues' that supports copying fields from the Epic or from a parent issue. Documentation is available [here](https://innovalog.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/JMWE/pages/68878492/Copy+field+value+from+linked+issues).

There's also this [related question on the Atlassian Community](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/Post-function-for-auto-assigning-issues-to-custom-field/qaq-p/281238) that mentions a few other plugins that could help.